# Independence Probability Exercise

Tags: probability, independence

Good morning.

I have some doubts regarding the solution that I've provided due to the shallow description of the problem.

Do you find any issues?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Instead of posting a picture of your solution, you should post the code you used here (which will render nicely via [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)).

Comment: I think the problem statement is too vague.  A sensible reading would be that $B,C$ have high probabilities of hearing the correct roll, and then some lower probability of hearing something random.  If that's your model, then knowing what $B$ heard is good evidence for what $A$ actually got, hence good evidence for what $C$ heard.

Comment: Regardless of how you read the problem, the first thing to do is to model the situation.  State clearly and explicitly what assumptions you are making.  Whatever model you use, the computations should be easy...the hard part is setting the situation up.

Comment: @lulu Are my assumptions plausible?

Comment: @user1729 Can I reuse latex code or should I customize?

Comment: @tech_1994 Pretty much, yes. I don't think enumerate and itemize work, but the site does that for you (use a `-` at the start of a line for itemize, and number lines instead of enumerate -- weirdly, the exact number doesn't matter).

Comment: I don't understand your assumptions.  What does $P(B)=P(B\,|\,C)$ mean?  Arfe you starting out by assuming that what $B$ hears is independent of what $C$ hears?  Whatever you mean by it, I would think it was false.  Start by stating in physical terms what you think the problem means.  The math will follow from that, not the other way round.

Comment: Consider a special case: Alice transmitted the number in binary and the phone issue is that there is a $p$ chance of any of the bits being flipped (no chance for multiple bits to be flipped). As you've already assumed, any error occurring for Bob is not related to any error occurring for Chad. How would you answer the questions in this case? How about the case where the phone error is that one bit in Alice's phone is bad, and that particular bit has a $p$ chance of being flipped in any transmission, but the other bits are always good?